# Joomla plugin {calls} - how to make them invisible in news display modules?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am using sigplus image gallery extension for JOomla and sometimes I need to put a call to its plugin by using {gallery /} statement. It works well and it's not visible in the article. But when I want this article to be visible on frontpage and I use any module from JED for that purpose (news scrollers/sliders) the statement is visible.
Look at the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq4St.png).

Is there a way to make this {statement} disappear? Or is there a slider module which doesn't show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the call to the plugin is that the modules you are using do not trigger the plugin code so it never gets replaced with a gallery. That's going to be an issue no matter what module you are using because the call if part of the content. Either that will show up or the gallery will unless you manipulate the code to do otherwise.

Your best bet is to modify which ever module you like best. If you look in the SIG plugin there is a regular expression they are using to replace the plugin call with the gallery code. Copy that and place it in your module, but instead up adding in the gallery code, replace the call with nothing and it will no longer appear in your module.